# How to delete a document from azure search once the document in cosmos db expires?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am currently using Azure Search Service whose data source is an Azure Cosmos DB. Currently, when the TTL on a document in Cosmos DB expires the corresponding document in the Search Service remains. How do I make sure the document is deleted from the Search Service as well?

I am aware that I can provide a field name to the 'Soft delete column' in the data source which will prevent that document from getting indexed but in my case, the document is not manually deleted (rather when the TTL expires) therefore the soft delete column cannot be set.

Comment: I believe you would need to reset the indexer in this case so that the index is populated from scratch. Unless you run the indexer again, there is no way for the Search Service to know that the document has been deleted from source.

Comment: So as every update in cosmos DB is communicated to the search service is there a way this can be communicated too?

Comment: I don't think so. That's why they propose using soft-delete approach.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you can add your response as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Can you update the search query to not return documents that have expired? It would leave old documents in the index but from the caller point of view all returned documents will be current.

Comment: @8163264128 How do I know which document is expired from the search service?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Azure Cosmos DB change feed to arrive at a solution to your problem. You can create an Azure Function that gets triggered whenever there is a change to your documents in cosmosDB. In the Azure function, you can write the logic to delete the document from cognitive search using REST apis.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/read-change-feed#azure-functions

This is a much cleaner approach compared to running the indexer again. If this logic doesn't work for you for whatever reason, you can use run the indexer as proposed by @gaurav mantri